# jquery validation while dynamically populating field with js method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation, however a few particular field values can be copied from other fields, example select menu option injections from a text field as well as math formulas populating text fields. The issue I'm having is when my js method populates a field, it still shows up as having a validation error. If I click in the field to give it focus, the validation error goes away.

Is there a way to remove the validation error after my js method has populated the field?

Code sample using trigger

```
        $("#rowInjector_1").tapestryFormInjector("trigger").live(Tapestry.AJAXFORMLOOP_ROW_ADDED, function(){
            setRequiredFields();
            var injectedRow = $(this).prev().attr("id");

            //adds new funding values to newly created row. 
            $("#" + injectedRow + " .orgKey").val(newOrgKey).trigger('change');
            $("#" + injectedRow + " .category").val(newBudgetCategory).trigger('change');
            $("#" + injectedRow + " .percentage").val(newPercentage).trigger('change');
            $("#" + injectedRow + " .amount").val(newTotal).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using? There's probably a function there that allows you to trigger form validation manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering a change event on the input you're copying the value into. Assigning a value to an input/select/textarea using `.val()` doesn't trigger them automatically. jQuery validation will re-fire once a change event occurs.

```
$('#yourInput').val(someOtherValue).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no results. I'm attaching code sample above.